# Error installing gherkin gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

When I update bundle using command `bundle update`:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.......    
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..    
Using rake (10.1.0)    
Using i18n (0.6.1)   
Using multi_json (1.8.2)   
Using activesupport (3.2.13)    
Using builder (3.0.4)   
Using activemodel (3.2.13)    
Using erubis (2.7.0)   
Using journey (1.0.4)    
Using rack (1.4.5)    
Using rack-cache (1.2)   
Using rack-test (0.6.2)    
Using hike (1.2.3)    
Using tilt (1.4.1)    
Using sprockets (2.2.2)   
Using actionpack (3.2.13)    
Using mime-types (1.25)   
Using polyglot (0.3.3)    
Using treetop (1.4.15)    
Using mail (2.5.4)    
Using actionmailer (3.2.13)    
Using arel (3.0.2)   
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)    
Using activerecord (3.2.13)    
Using activeresource (3.2.13)    
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)    
Using bootstrap-sass (2.1.0.0)    
Using will_paginate (3.0.3)   
Using bootstrap-will_paginate (0.0.6)    
Using mini_portile (0.5.1)   
Using nokogiri (1.6.0)   
Using ffi (1.9.0)    
Using childprocess (0.3.9)   
Using rubyzip (0.9.9)    
Using websocket (1.0.7)    
Using selenium-webdriver (2.35.1)   
Using xpath (0.1.4)    
Installing capybara (1.1.2)    
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)    
Using execjs (2.0.2)   
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)    
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)    
Using json (1.8.1)   
Using rdoc (3.12.2)    
Using thor (0.18.1)    
Using railties (3.2.13)    
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)   
Installing diff-lcs (1.1.3)  

NoMethodError: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass   
An error occurred while installing gherkin (2.12.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.

Make sure that `gem install gherkin -v '2.12.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

And when I try : `gem install gherkin -v '2.12.2'`

```
$ gem install gherkin -v '2.12.2'

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)

    undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using (ruby -v)?

Comment: ruby 1.9.3p392  and rails 3.2

Comment: What about gem version? (gem --version)

Comment: You could try upgrading rubygems and see if that helps (gem update --system)

Comment: You can also get a backtrace when installing gems that might give you more info. Add --backtrace to the install command.

Comment: gem update --system was successful

Comment: ERROR:  Error installing gherkin:
        invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined me
thod `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/
ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/gherkin-2.12.2-x86-mingw32.gem

Comment: I was going to suggest opening an issue on GitHub, but it looks like you already did. Good luck!